# Comparing dates using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a date that looks like this: `2014-10-01 12:35:29.440`

the table looks like this:

```
ORDER 1 | 2014-07-31 00:00:00.000

ORDER 2 | 2015-07-31 00:00:00.000
```

sorry i wanted ORDER 2 to show up.. As my get date returns todays date and that is GREATER than 2014-07-31 00:00:00.000

Here is what i have tried:

```
SELECT TOP 1 NAME
FROM ORDER_DATES
WHERE GETDATE() > ORDER_DATE
ORDER BY NAME DESC
```

Comment: Are you really storing a date as a character string and not as a date/time?

Comment: Its stored as date time...

Comment: What does your first line mean?  Your query doesn't have a date in that format.

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious he is talking about the current date-time

Comment: Use sqlfiddle to create a working example or post your table DDL, and check the time on server where are SQL Server installed.

Comment: Your query will return "ORDER 1" see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/21fbc/1 ; isn't that what you expected?

Comment: datetime fields are NOT STORED "in a format" (they are in fact stored as 2 integers) and the visible format can be adapted to suit your taste and cultural preferences. When discussing these fields it is sufficient to know it is defined as datetime

Comment: sorry i wanted ORDER 2 to show up.. As my get date returns todays date and that is GREATER than `2014-07-31 00:00:00.000`

Comment: You realize order 2 is 2015 right? 'GetDate()' (today) is *not* greater than anything in 2015

Comment: IF it doesnt match the date then it needs to return the next row. Which is ORDER 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question still isn't quite worded in a way that is conducive to what you need... but I think I understand what you want now based on the comments.

Based on the comment:

> IF it doesnt match the date then it needs to return the next row.
>   Which is ORDER 2

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT TOP 1 name
FROM ORDER_DATES o
INNER JOIN (
    -- This subquery finds the first date that occurs *after* the current date
    SELECT MIN(ORDER_DATE) AS ORDER_DATE
    FROM ORDER_DATES
    WHERE ORDER_DATE > GETDATE()
) minDateAfterToday ON o.ORDER_DATE = minDateAfterToday.ORDER_DATE
ORDER BY name
```

This would work a lot better if you had an ID field in the table, but this *should* work with the given data, you'll potentially run into issues if you have two orders on the exact same date.

EDIT:

here's a fiddle showing the query in action:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f3057/1

Answer (score 0):

[DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)  will come handy, also you have to order by `ORDER_DATE`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 NAME
FROM ORDER_DATES
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,ORDER_DATE,GETDATE())>0
ORDER BY  ORDER_DATE DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are querying against right table

```
declare @dt datetime  = cast('2014-10-01 12:35:29.440' as datetime), @dt2  datetime= cast('2014-07-31 00:00:00.000' as datetime);

print(case when @dt > @dt2 then 1 else 0 end);
```

This piece of script shows output 1 i.e. condition should match for ORDER 1.

Verify if you are missing some thing.

---

**Edit** as per change to original question:

here the condition needed be reverted as date value is in future which is greater than current date

new query will be as

```
SELECT TOP 1 NAME
FROM ORDER_DATES
WHERE  ORDER_DATE > GETDATE()
ORDER BY NAME DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write as:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM ORDER_DATES
WHERE cast(GETDATE()as date) > cast (ORDER_DATE as date)
ORDER BY NAME DESC
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/KHPX8378)</kbd>